# Adaptive Cards Cannot add description property

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, spfx-aces

I am trying to build Image Adaptive Card for the first time, I thought "Description" Property can be added how it can added in the normal web part SPFx. I was wondering how to add "Description" to "ICardParameters"

CardView.ts

```
  public get data(): IImageCardParameters {
    return {
      primaryText: strings.PrimaryText,
      imageUrl: require('../assets/MicrosoftLogo.png'),
      title: this.properties.title,
      description: this.properties.description --- Type '{ primaryText: string; imageUrl: string; title: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ICardParameters'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'description' does not exist in type 'ICardParameters'.
    };
  }
```

PropertyPane.ts

```
PropertyPaneTextField('description',{
                  label: strings.Description,
                  multiline: true,
                  rows: 5
                })
```

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Sure, Thank you. even i tried out some of approach but did not work though.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Microsoft official documentation of [IImageCardParameters interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base/iimagecardparameters) it has two properties:

- imageUrl
- primaryText

Also, this interface extends the [IBaseCardParameters interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base/ibasecardparameters) which has below proerties:

- iconAltText
- iconProperty
- title

So, you can only specify above known properties and cannot use 'description' as it does not exist in the interface type you are using.

Comment: Any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research and testing, we cannot add "Description" . IImageCardParameters interface only has `imageUrl` and `primaryText` properties. Thanks for your understanding.

More information for reference: [IImageCardParameters interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base/iimagecardparameters?view=sp-typescript-latest)

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.